# How to send a string from an Apple script

Tags: applescript, realbasic, appleevents

I code in REALbasic.

Whenever I receive an IM via iChat, iChat runs an applescript and sends to it the last message received.  I need to somehow forward this message as a string to the app I'm writing in REALbasic.  REALbasic is able to respond to AppleEvents but I don't now how to implement this or if I'm even in the right ball park.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I haven´t used RB in ages, but maybe the following link (just a quick google) might be a starting point?

http://www.106automation.com/page2/RB/RB.html

(the link to download the example files is actually the title of the page, so click "REALBasic & Applescript")